# Any way to access an instance variable from inside a simple function in Lua?

Tags: class, lua, codea

How to create a "pseudo-instance" variable or access an instance variable from a simple function defined inside a class in Lua ?

I did'nt find any way to access an instance variable from a simple function inside a class. I can only access it if the function is a method i.e. with the prefix of the class before ( anyClass:method() ) usinf "self." keyword. Thanks ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "instance variable"? Also, Lua doesn't have classes; it has tables. So how are you using a Lua table to mimic a class?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment. I use Codea on iPad witch is Lua based. I don't know how but Codea mimics classes. I need to access an instance variable of my class (a "self." variable) but self. is not accessible from a simple function, only from a method and I don't know how to proceed then.

Comment: Instance variables are typically stored as table entries, so you can access them outside of methods with `myObject.instanceVariable`.

Comment: If it helps, you can write the function definition with an explicit self parameter, yet call it with `:`. The distinction between method and non-method functions is simply a matter of style and is independently chosen by the definition and each caller.